# Toggle visibility of element onblur and onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick, event-handling, onblur

I have a `div` element used as a toggle, and a `select` element which shall be shown/hidden in the way that:

(1) When clicking the toggle, the `select` shall be shown and focused, if it was hidden

(2) When clicking the toggle, the `select` shall be hidden, if it was visible

(3) When the select looses focus, it shall be hidden.

Now there is this edge case when the `select` has focus and user clicks the toggle -- then both events, `onclick` and `onblur`, are fired and cancel each other, at least in Firefox:

```
<div id="toggle">toggle</div>
<div>foobar</div>
<select id="select" multiple>
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>bar</option>
</select>
```

```
document.getElementById('toggle').onclick = function () {
    var select = document.getElementById('select');
    select.style.display = select.style.display === 'none' ? 'inline' : 'none';
        select.focus();
    };

document.getElementById('select').onblur = function () {
    this.style.display = 'none';
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2wrxykpd/

I tried checking `event.explicitOriginalTarget` in the `onblur` function (online hide `select` if target of the `onblur` event is not the toggle), which would work in Firefox, but not in Chrome.

So what would be the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution myself, also see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614773/javascript-newbie-seems-that-onblur-of-one-element-is-overriding-the-onclick?rq=1).

The idea is to add `mousedown` and `mouseup` events to the toggle. Then the order of execution will be

(1) toggle.onmousedown

(2) select.onblur

(3) toggle.onmouseup

(4) toggle.onclick

That is, inside the `mousedown`/`mouseup` events we can set and reset an ignore flag; the flag will then only be set inside the `onblur`, in the `onclick` it will already have been reset.

So we got

```
document.getElementById('toggle').onclick = function () {
  var select = document.getElementById('select');
  select.style.display = select.style.display === 'none' ? 'inline' : 'none';
  select.focus();
};
document.getElementById('toggle').onmousedown = function () {
  document.getElementById('select').ignoreClickEvent = true;
};
document.getElementById('toggle').onmouseup = function () {
  document.getElementById('select').ignoreClickEvent = false;
};

document.getElementById('select').onblur = function () {
  if (!this.ignoreClickEvent) {
    this.style.display = 'none';
  }
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ezt0sonj/

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to focus on the toggle and then check against the relatedTarget:

```js
var select = document.getElementById('select');
var toggle = document.getElementById('toggle');

toggle.addEventListener('focus', function (event) {
 if (event.relatedTarget !== select) {
   var isHidden = select.classList.toggle('hidden')

    if (!isHidden) {
      select.focus();
    }
  }
  
  toggle.blur()
});

select.addEventListener('blur', function () {
 select.classList.add('hidden')
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="toggle">toggle</button>
</div>
<div>
  <select id="select" class="hidden" multiple>
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>bar</option>
  </select>
</div>
```